# .read() reinterpret_cast<char *> c++

Tags: c++, file-io, reinterpret-cast

I've got a file with some doubles (9 to be exact, for a 3x3 matrix) written in binary. I'm trying to make use of them as the real double value they represent (the number ej: 5.66 / -1.882 / etc..).

They are placed in the file one after another without any spaces: 3.245-2.453.253...... and they are exactly 9 numbers.

Then I have an struct with a pointer pointing to a vector of 9 slots (0-8) which I want to fill with the value of the doubles, SO, here's what I'm trying so far:

```
struct input{
    double data*;
    double myvector[9];
};
```

and then

```
input test;
test.data = test.myvector;
ifstream f(file,ios::binary);

f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(test.data),sizeof(double)*3*3);
```

Then when I went to check the values with some simple std::cout I got some weird numbers printed into console:

-0.1667 was printed as: -1,57218e+26

Is this supposed to happen? If not, what I'm doing wrong? In case I'm doing it right, what do I have to do with this value to get my "-0.1667"?

Thank you.

EDIT: By the time they created the file they had a pointer (pointing to a vector of doubles like my example) and they just made a f.write(whatever you put here); and that's what I mean when I sayd the numbers are one after another, there are no black characters in between any double there.

EDIT 2: full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct input{
    double data*;
    double myvector[9];
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    input test;
    test.data=test.myvector;

    ifstream f(argv[1], ios::binay); // argv[1] is the file EJ: ./program myfile
    f.read(reinterpret_cast <char *> (test.data), sizeof(double)*9); // being 9 values.

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){

        cout << test.data[i] << endl;

    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is in binary format?

Comment: The program picks the bytes, not the value through f.read()

Comment: @jrok Absolutely. They are given as an example to test the f.read() (as I'm still learning).

Comment: When you say "They are placed in the file one after another without any *spaces*", I can't help to think you've got a text file with textual representation of doubles. Reading bytes won't work in that case, of course.

Comment: @Zasito If you do `type file` [Dos/Windows] or `cat file` [Linux/MacOS/Solaris/etc] (or open the file in a text editor), do you see numbers or "weird stuff that doesn't look like anything sensible?

Comment: @jrok what I mean is that when it got written they didn't write an string with the doubles and a blank character in between each other. If you open this file (with gedit or w/e) there are these weird symbols which aren't numbers.

Comment: @MatsPetersson weird stuff that doesn't look like anything sensible.

Comment: What is your code that checks the values?

Comment: @MikeKinghan cout << test.data[0] << endl; with a for (0 through 8)

Comment: Please post both the code that writes the values [including some initializing of the values] and the complete code that reads and prints the values.

Comment: Is this your actual code?  `ios::binay` is a typo (it should be `binary`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real numbers are stored as floating-point numbers. floating-point arithmetic is not exact: The value of the number is stored as a significant number of fixed digits, and an exponent of fixed digits.

When you try to print a floating-point value as a string, the number is formatted in "decimal-real-number" format. For this formatting, the value of the number is rounded (You want a representation with certain precission, not infinite digits).

Because of this formatting, what you see as "-0.1667" its really the rounded form of the real value. The other notation, -1.572218e+26 , is much similar to the true floating-point representation.

I supposed that when you talk about "-0.1667", you are talking about the original value you printed to the file. But -1.667 is the value that you see when outputs the value of the variable (on the console, for example), not? This is the point: -1.667 is a rounded value. The true value is "-1.572218e+26".

You are storing the flotating-point values in a file in binary-mode, so you print in the file **the real representation of the number** (The binary representation). When you read the file, you read the same value that you stored before. When you puts this value in std::cout, cout prints the value, without rounding (This can be configured).

If you want rounded format, you could use [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) to configure the format.

Comment: Oh! that explains quite a lot. So got 1 last question, if in that same program I want to use those values for something else(for example using them for some other functions), what do I do to use the rounded value. How do I make use of setprecission?

Comment: `setprecision` is only for printing the value. You don't need to worry about it when passing the float to functions. Though I haven't been able to reproduce the scientific notation. I only ever get tiny rounding errors.

Comment: @mwerschy then, if I use that notation is basically the same as if I use the rounded one?

Comment: Remember: The machine works with the real representation, without round. If you want to use a rounded version of the original value, you  would to implement a rounding function. If you use modern C++, a round() function [is provided by the standard library since C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round)

Comment: @Manu343726 The machine doesn't actually work with the real representation ;) `float` can't do that. It rounds whatever you give it to the nearest thing it can save in that format. @Zasito Not sure what you mean? [E Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) is another way of writing the number if that's your question.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, i meant the machine (floatintg-point) representation instead of "decimal-rounded-format". Sorry. That must be "true" or "flotating-point", not "real".

Comment: @Manu343726 let me put an example: I've got that rounded value (-0.1667) and I want to use it to make a simple addition (2+(-0.1667)). I just tried this with the unrounded version (-1,57218e+26) and it shows me exactly the same (-1,57218e+26). I just don't want to work anymore with the unrounded version (-1,57218e+26) after I've read it. What to do?

Comment: Well since I'm not sure how your even getting that I can't really help you. I don't see how it should cause any problems, the float will be stored normally in memory, `std::cout` just seems to be printing it strangely for you.

Comment: Rounded version its only a way to print the number in a string. The value with you are working is -1,57218e+26. But as @mwerschy notes, dont worry with that. Think that you are computing two real numbers, anything more. The representation is not the point.

Comment: Flotating-point operations have precission errors. This makes, for example, the boolean operation "(24.0)+(24.0)-(24.0) == 24.0" does not to evaluate to true (addition and substraction have arithmetic errors). But i think this is not your case, because 2 is toooooo large. You have to be doing anything wrong.

Comment: @mwerschy Well here's the deal: I'm working with an image, and aplying a filter (9 double values through an algorithm) which changes the image (EJ: get's a better contrast or wathever). When I place the values manually (data[0][0]=-0.1667 etc...) it works smoothly. Then when I read that exact value from binary, It doesn't work properly (always shows a completely black image). That's why I'm at a loss, as reading what you say to me, it should work just fine as the values are the same?, but it doesn't. That's why I wanted the "original" value...

Comment: Well you can't get the original values because float doesn't save them. Try running [this](http://pastebin.com/9VdHYm9h) in your compiler and see if it uses the E Notation too. Just enter 9 numbers, it'll save them to file and read them again :) See if that works properly. And nobody flame me for `system("pause")` please ;)

Comment: @mwerschy it shows it with like 20 decimals :O w/o the e+[number]

Comment: Yh exactly 20 decimals. `std::cout.precision(20);` So no E notation? Try removing the `precision` and see what happens. If it still works fine, only truncates, I blame your code ;)

Comment: Well then... I can't help you. Your code is buggy somewhere else than you showed us.